# KnnImpute Matlab

Tags: matlab, missing-data, knn

In matlab there is a function called KnnImpute that permit to replace missing values in a matrix using Knn Algorithm. Looking at the http://www.mathworks.it/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/knnimpute.html I've found that it searchs through matrix's columns but I'd like to search for neighbors checking along rows. Is there a function that permit to do that? Where could I find matlab code to realize what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just transpose the matrix using `'` and run `knnimpute`?

Comment: This sounds right, I'm surprised this isn't the default behaviour.

Comment: Me too moreover because usually this function is used on matrix that represents dataset so on columns we've got different attributes!

Comment: The reason the default isn't the way round you're expecting is that the function is from Bioinformatics Toolbox. Many bioinformatics researchers store their data with genes (variables) as rows and observations as columns, because they measure so many genes and have relatively few observations.